# My Crypto is not working right, it keeps resetting

Tags: python

I was working on a cryptocurrency and everything else works but this, you can have a mine once, but then you can't after one time because the balance is the same. It should be simple. I need help with the balance and saving it and being able to mine more than once,
You will probly be able to fix this instantly

```
    import os
import time
from anthonys_balance import lbalance





balance = 1

user = input("Username:")
f = open(user + "'s file", "w")

username = user
ubalance = balance
userbalance = f'{balance}{username}'
log = f'{user} has a balance of {lbalance} Coinon'

y=f'{user}s_balance.py'
if os.path.exists(y):
    if os.path.isfile(y):
        print("file is present")
else:
 f = open(user + "s_balance.py", "x")
 f.write (f'lbalance = {ubalance}')
 f.close()



f = open(user + "'s file", "w")
f.write(str(log))
f.close()




userfile = user + "s_balance.txt"

os.system("clear")

def select():
  from anthonys_balance import lbalance
  print(f'{user} has a balance of {lbalance} Coinon')

  print("Mine = 1")
  print("Send = 2")
  options = input("Selection:")

  if options == "1":
     def mine():
      x = 1
      if x == 1:
       time.sleep(3)
       #import user + "'s balance.py"

       from anthonys_balance import lbalance
       lnbalance = lbalance +1
       f = open(user + "'s file", "w")
       f.write(f'{user} has a balance of {lnbalance +1} Coinons')
       f.close()
       f = open(f'{user}s_balance.py', "w")
       f.write(f'lbalance = {lnbalance +1}')
       f.close()
       print(f'{user} has a balance of {lnbalance +1} Coinons')
       print("mine success")
       input("Continue?")
       f = open(user + "'s file", "w")
       f.write(f'{user} has a balance of {lnbalance +1} Coinons')
       f.close()

      mine()
  mine()
pass
select()
```

Comment: please add more details so that there is an input, an expected output and some runnable code, so people can replicate your problem

Comment: Just run the code as the username "anthony" because i accedently hard coded that

Comment: You haven't included all the code.... `from anthonys_balance import lbalance` <-- this module is missing

Comment: `import` loads code only once so using `from anthonys_balance import lbalance` many times (inside function) is useless. It can't reset this value.

Comment: first you should use `print()` to see values in variables and which part of code is executed - it is called `"print debuging"`. maybe this will show you where you set wrong value.

Comment: I thin your problem is that you want to use `import` to load new value from file but `import` remebers already imported file and it doesn't load it again. You should use normal text file or `json`, `csv`, `.ini`, `.yaml` or `pickle` for data.

Comment: to make code more readble you could define `mine()` outside `select()` and you could put all functions directly after imports - see more [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Pythn Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-008/)

Comment: you could also create functions to load and save data, and function to append text to log file - mode `a` instead of `w` (which remove previous content). This way code could be more readable.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't run it but I see few problems

1. you have mess in code. To make code more readable you could

   - put `mine()` outside `select()`,
   - convert some code into function - ie. read_data, save_data, log,
   - put all functions directly after `import`
   - send values to function as arguments

(see more in [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for PythonCode](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/))

2. you use `import` to load data but `import` reads file only once and it remember it - so it doesn't load again the same file. Python assumes that code doesn't change and data should be in files like `.txt`, `.json`, `.ini`, `.yaml`, `pickle, etc. or in database

---

This is my version with all changes.

I keep `balance` in dictionary `data` and I save it in `.json` - so I can keep other information `data` and save it in file - ie. username.

I load data only once - at start - and later I uses value which I have in memory and only I save new value in file. If there is no file at start then I create new one with default values.

I use `while True` to run code many times and user may select `X` to exit it.

```
import os
import time
import json
import datetime

# --- functions ---

def log(username, text):
    dt = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y.%m.%d %H:%M.%S')
    filename = f'{username}.log'
    with open(filename, "a") as f: # append
        f.write(f'{dt} {text} \n')

def load_data(username):
    filename = f'{username}.json'
    
    if os.path.exists(filename) and os.path.isfile(filename):
        with open(filename) as f:
            data = json.load(f)
    else:
        data = None
        
    return data

def save_data(username, data):
    filename = f'{username}.json'
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
         json.dump(data, f)
    

def select(username, data):
    while True:
        print(f'{username} has a balance of {data["balance"]} Coinons')
    
        print("1. Mine")
        print("2. Send")
        print("X. Exit")
        
        answer = input("Selection:")
    
        answer = answer.upper().strip()
        
        if answer == "X":
            return
        
        elif answer == "1":
            mine(username, data)
        
        elif answer == "2":
            print('not created')
            #send(username, data)
    
def mine(username, data):
    time.sleep(3)
    
    data['balance'] += 1
    save_data(username, data)
    
    log(username, f'{username} has balance {data["balance"]} Coinon')

    print(f'{username} has a balance of {data["balance"]} Coinons')
    print("mine success")

    input("Press any key to continue.")
 
# --- main ---

username = input("Username: ")

# load data from file or use default value
data = load_data(username)
if not data:
    data = {'balance': 1, "username": username}
    save_data(username, data)

log(username, f'{username} has balance {data["balance"]} Coinon')

os.system("clear")
    
select(username, data)
```